# Session Destroy options in shopping cart application

Tags: php, session, shopping-cart

Hi all I am developing a web application which doesn't have login and logout options. This is an Ecommerce site. So to persist ordering of different products i am saving the order data in a session. But even after i closed browser or tab also session is not destroying. I am not explicitly destroying so how to destroy session in these situations.

Please give some insights. New to PHP development.

```
session_start();
function addtocart($productid,$quantity,$amount){

    if($productid === "" or $quantity<1) return;

    if(is_array($_SESSION['cart'])){
        if(product_exists($productid)) return;
        $max=count($_SESSION['cart']);
        $_SESSION['cart'][$max]['productid']=$productid;
        $_SESSION['cart'][$max]['quantity']=$quantity;
        $_SESSION['cart'][$max]['amount'] =$amount;
    }
    else{
        $_SESSION['cart']=array();
        $_SESSION['cart'][0]['productid']=$productid;
        $_SESSION['cart'][0]['quantity']=$quantity;
        $_SESSION['cart'][0]['amount']=$amount;
    }
}

function product_exists($pid){

$max=count($_SESSION['cart']);
$flag=0;
for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
    if($pid === $_SESSION['cart'][$i]['productid']){
        $flag=1;
        break;
    }
}
return $flag;
```

}

Comment: Closing the browser will typically end the session, so something else is going on. You may need to post some code...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this, but I think session variables are stored in cookies. That may be the reason your session is still present after closing the browser.

Take a look at [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php) link. You can free your session variables with `session_unset()`

Answer (score 0):

just use `session_destroy();` 
this will surely destroy all stored sessions

you can use it like this

```
if(isset($_POST['destroy_btn']))
    {
     session_destroy();
     header('location: homepage.php'); 
     //redirect or refresh it after destroying the sessions
    }
```

And also, browsers have an option called session restore, that restores your last sessions when you reopen your browser. just turn off this option.

Comment: I have to call this session_destroy() only when tab closes or browser closes.

Comment: ah. i think you have to turn off "session restore" feature of your browser. try it.